# Setting up a tornado web service in production with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, tornado

I have been developing a web service in tornado for the last few months, in my test environment  to run the service I use:

```
python index.py
```

index.py is my tornado application handler that listens on port 8001. I then request from the web service using `http://localhost:8001`. I am now deploying my test environment to a staging environment that should mirror production. How do I go about running tornado in production? I'm guessing I need to create some sort of daemon for the application but I have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are a few tools you can use.

First, [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

Supervisord is a "process control system", you configure your processes and let Supervisor manage them, it'll restart them if they fail, make managing them easier and keep them running in the background

Here's a sample supervisor config file

```
[program:myprogram] 
process_name=MYPROGRAM%(process_num)s
directory=/var/www/apps/myapp 
command=/var/www/apps/myapp/virtualenv/bin/python index.py --PORT=%(process_num)s
startsecs=2
user=youruser
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp/out-%(process_num)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp/err-%(process_num)s.log
numprocs=4
numprocs_start=14000
```

With that config, Supervisor will start 4 (`numprocs`) instances of index.py on ports 14001-14004 (`numprocs_start`). We pass the `--PORT=%(process_num)s` to get each process to start on a different port. You should change `numprocs` and `numprocs_start` to suit your environment/equipment. Generally we run 2xCPU cores processes (so a quad core processor would have 8 processes) but that can vary hugely based on what your processes do and how much blocking there is in your code.

Next, configure NGINX to forward requests to your site

```
   upstream myappbackend {
            server 127.0.0.1:14001  max_fails=3     fail_timeout=1s;
            server 127.0.0.1:14002  max_fails=3     fail_timeout=1s;
            server 127.0.0.1:14003  max_fails=3     fail_timeout=1s;
            server 127.0.0.1:14004  max_fails=3     fail_timeout=1s;
    }

    server {
            listen                                          4.5.6.7:80;
            server_name                                     example.com;

            access_log      /var/log/nginx/myapp.log  main;


            location / {
                    proxy_set_header                Host            $host;
                    proxy_set_header                X-Real-Ip       $remote_addr;
                    proxy_pass                      http://myappbackend/;
            }
    }
```

That config should be modified dependent on your application and the way it works, that is a very minimal configuration and will almost certainly need expanding on but that should be enough to get you started

Comment: Is it nginx or supervisord that handles which process is used when the  URL is accessed? Or do I need more software to manage this.

Comment: and could you explain why you are starting the process at 14000?

Comment: nginx passes the request to one of the backends. Supervisor only takes  care of the process management ( live/dead/restart ). For the port, you can choose anything you want unless it collides with some other app that is listening one of the ports