# Can i run multiple processes (each with different port) using systemd?

Tags: supervisord, systemd

I have following supervisord config(copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14752544/4734180)):

```
[program:myprogram] 
process_name=MYPROGRAM%(process_num)s
directory=/var/www/apps/myapp 
command=/var/www/apps/myapp/virtualenv/bin/python index.py --PORT=%(process_num)s
startsecs=2
user=youruser
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp/out-%(process_num)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp/err-%(process_num)s.log
numprocs=4
numprocs_start=14000
```

Can i do same thing with systemd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A systemd unit can include [specifiers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) which may be used to write a generic unit service that will be instantiated several times.

Example based on your `supervisord` config: `/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My awesome daemon on port %i
After=network.target

[Service]
User=youruser
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/apps/myapp
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/www/apps/myapp/virtualenv/bin/python index.py --PORT=%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may then enable / start as many instances of that service using by example:

```
# systemctl start mydaemon@4444.service
```

Article with more examples on Fedora Magazine.org: [systemd: Template unit files](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/).